# How to get top agent name who processed more application from the given two tables

Tags: sql

The tables are:

```
Table1

Agent_Id    Name
1           Vijay
2           Rajesh
3           Satish
4           Anji


Table2

Case_Id  Stage     Login_Time   Logout_time  Agent_id   Status
101      Maker     10:20        10:30        2          Success
102      Maker     10:25        10:35        1          Success
103      Maker     10:40        10:50        2          Success
101      Checker   10:45        11:00        3          Success
101      Approver  11:15        11:30        2          Success
102      Checker   10:50        11:00        1          Reject
102      Maker     11:15        11:45        4          Reverify
103      Checker   11:30        11:40        2          Reject
```

I want to get the Top Agent names with who processed more applications.

I tried:

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table2.Status, count (*)
FROM Table1, Table2
LEFT JOIN Agent Table
ON Agent Table. Agent_Id = Case_transaction_details.Id
GROUP BY Table1.Name
```

Comment: tag your database name

Answer (score 1):

Where does the third table come from?

Also, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

So:

```
SELECT t1.Agent_id, t1.Name, COUNT(t2.Agent_id)
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t2.Agent_Id = t1.Agent_Id AND
        t2.Status = 'Success'  -- I assume you want this
GROUP BY t1.Agent_id, t1.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(t2.Agent_id) DESC;
```

Notes:

- This counts only "success" statuses, which I am guessing you want.  (If not, remove that condition.)
- This uses a `LEFT JOIN` so all agents are included.
- This includes `Agent_id` in the aggregation, just in case two agents have the same name.
- You can add `FETCH FIRST` or `LIMIT` or `SELECT TOP` (depending on the database) to limit the results to a particular size.

Answer (score 0):

if it is mysql then you can try like below

```
SELECT Table1.Name,Table1.Agent_Id, count (*) as cnt
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Agent_Id = Table2.Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Name,Table1.Agent_Id
order by cnt desc limit 1
```

in case of different RDBMS syntax will be varried like for sql server you need `top`

Answer (score 0):

Try this-(for MSSQL)

```
SELECT TOP 1 T1.Agent_Id, T1.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Agent_Id = T2.Agent_Id
WHERE T2.Status = 'Success'
GROUP BY T1.Agent_Id,T1.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`````
SELECT a.Name, COUNT(c.Agent_id) as Processed_Applications
FROM agent_name as a
LEFT JOIN
case_transaction_details as c ON
a.Agent_id= c.Agent_id 
GROUP BY a.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(c.Agent_id) DESC;````
`````

Comment: please describe how this solve the problem. it is more easy to the user

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". Formatting is important on SO; Help is available to show how to use it when editing your text. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" will help too. Also, please explain why this should be the selected solution, and how it works; The goal is to educate, not just toss out code.